# Получить номер телефона из списка контактов

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить номер по имени пользователя из списка контактов. Я реализовал интент:

```
final Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
mSuspectButton = v.findViewById(R.id.crime_suspect);
mSuspectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivityForResult(pickContact, REQUEST_CONTACT);
    }
});
```

Потом получаю имя пользователя:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Date date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.getExtraDate());
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate(mCrime.getDateString());
    }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && data != null){
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        //определение полей, значения которых должны быть возвращены запросом
        String[] queryFields = new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        try (Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String suspect = cursor.getString(0);
            mCrime.setSuspect(suspect);
            mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);
        }

    }
}
```

И теперь мне нужно получить номер телефона этого пользователя и записать его в отдельную переменную. Новичек и как эту задачу реализовать не пойму. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно немного сменить URI интента и добавить поля для запроса. В общем вот так будет выглядеть код:

```
    final Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    Button mSuspectButton = v.findViewById(R.id.crime_suspect);
    mSuspectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(pickContact, REQUEST_CONTACT);
        }
    });
```

И код в `onActivityResult()`:

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Date date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.getExtraDate());
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate(mCrime.getDateString());
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && data != null){
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        //определение полей, значения которых должны быть возвращены запросом
        String[] queryFields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        try (Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String suspect = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            mCrime.setSuspect(suspect);
            mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);

            //проверяем, есть ли у контакта номер
            boolean hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0;

            //если есть номер, получаем его
            if (hasPhoneNumber) {
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                //тут делаем с номером, что нужно

            }
        }
    }
```